# Doctrine - FindBy on One To Many relation

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

lets suppose i have 'product' entity

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="es_product")
*/
class Product extends \Kdyby\Doctrine\Entities\BaseEntity {

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 */
private $id;

... 

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductLang", mappedBy="product", cascade={"ALL"}, indexBy="iso")
 */
protected $contentLang;

...
```

and ProductLang entity

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="es_product_lang")
*/
class ProductLang  extends \Kdyby\Doctrine\Entities\BaseEntity {

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\App\Modules\CmsAdmin\Model\Lang")
 */
protected $lang;

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="contentLang")
 */
protected $product;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $name;
```

as you can see there is a one to many connection between Product and ProductLang

The question is, is there a possibility to use doctrine's 'findBy()' method from 'Product' repository to find products based on productLang.name?

I know i can do something like

```
productLangRepo->findBy( [ 'product' => $product, 'name' => $name])
```

but I need to stay in productRepo, that means, I would like to do  something like

```
productRepo->findBy( [ 'contentLang["iso"]->name' => $name ])
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It looks like QueryBuilder is only solution

Answer (score 4):

i think you are approaching this the wrong way. What you should do is use findBy on a language repo:

```
$language = productLangRepo->findBy(array('name' => $name));
```

and then get the connected products from that (since you have a 2 way connection):

```
$productsForLanguage = $language->getProduct() //btw since it is many to one it should be named products not product.
```

Then you will have a Product collection that you can filter. If you still want to go from the product repo side you will have to use DQL or Criteria to write more complex filters.